# Override default breakpoints in Magento2

Tags: css, themes, magento2

I want to override default breakpoints in magento2 css. suggest any ideas how to do this?

E.g. in magento2 default breakpoints are

```
@screen__xxs: 320px;

@screen__xs: 480px;

@screen__s: 640px;

@screen__m: 768px;

@screen__l: 1024px;

@screen__xl: 1440px;
```

I want to override them by

```
@screen__xxs: 320px;

@screen__xs: 479px;

@screen__s: 767px;

@screen__m: 991px;

@screen__l: 1440px;

@screen__xl: 2150px;
```

On Devdocs magento I found the way to add new but failed to override existing alls.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your theme create a file under following directory structure:

`<Namespace>/<Theme>/web/css/source/lib/variables/_responsive.less`
Now here add your custom variables:

```
@screen__xxs: 320px;

@screen__xs: 479px;

@screen__s: 767px;

@screen__m: 991px;

@screen__l: 1440px;

@screen__xl: 2150px;
```

This file would override the default magento variables. Hence you would have customized breakpoints. On deployment the directory would be created:

`pub/static/frontend/<Namespace>/<ThemeName>/en_US/css/source/lib/variables/_responsive.less`
And you would see the default breakpoints are overridden.